# Remove slice element and reinitialize slice

Tags: go

What is the correct way to remove an item from a slice in GO?

Also, what is the correct way to reinitialize a slice i.e. completely empty it but still keep it?

Comment: By "remove," do you mean remove in the list sense? So, for example, removing 3 from [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] would give you [1, 2, 4, 5]?

Comment: Please show some code for this problem.

Comment: Also, by "reinitialize" do you mean restore to the value it had when it was first allocated?

Comment: @joshlf13 - yes exactly that: 1,2,4,5 would be the result.  And reinitialize as in a completely empty slice

Comment: It sounds like you've been working most with interpreted languages. The idea of "removing" an element from an array doesn't really exist in a language as low-level as Go. I'd suggest reading or watching a tutorial on C arrays first - it might help explain some of the misconceptions that you probably have coming from a higher-level language. I haven't watched the whole thing, but this video appears to do a very good job: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fu-s9B8tdUg

If I'm right about where your confusion is, you'll probably be able to answer your own question once you learn how C arrays work.

Comment: (btw, when I say "C array," I really mean arrays in any language as low-level as C).

Comment: (also, sorry about how introductory that video is; the later parts are helpful)

Comment: @joshlf13 - you are correct in your assumption.  I come from a background of using higher level languages.  Would you suggest that learning c before go is a good idea?  Im learning go purely for educational reasons

Comment: Actually, I'd say learning Go first (assuming you ever learn C later, which is by no means necessary) is a much better idea. C is a great language if you want to learn REALLY low-level stuff, but Go is a fine language to teach you low-level programming.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are misunderstanding the nature of a slice.  A slice is like an `ArrayList` in Java.  It is backed by a regular array and grows/shrinks on demand.  Operations on a slice have the same performance characteristic as those you would expect on an `ArrayList`.

Your question(s) would make more sense if slices were the `LinkedList` equivalent.  For that, look up [Package list](http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/).

Nevertheless, here's how to do this.  Most comes directly from [SliceTricks](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks), but I think it's good practice on SO to not refer to links and provide the answer right here.

### Way to remove an item from a slice

This is something that you can do in any programming language, in O(1) time, if you don't care about order.  If you care about order, this is not going to work.

The idea is to overwrite the item you want to remove with the last item in the slice, then reduce the size of the slice by one.

```
arr := []string{ "allo", "hello", "bye", "chao" }

// delete "bye"
deleteIdx := 2 
lastIdx := len(arr) - 1

// arr = { "allo", "hello", "chao", "chao" }
arr[deleteIdx] = arr[lastIdx]

// arr = { "allo", "hello", "chao" } ... "chao" 
arr = arr[:lastIdx - 1]
```

You can do that [in a single step (SliceTricks)](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks):

```
arr[deleteIdx], arr = arr[len(arr)-1], arr[:len(arr) - 1]
```

However, like mentionned in the SliceTricks article, some type of values will not be garbage collected if you don't `nil` them, as the backing array behind the slice still holds a reference to them.  The solution is to `nil` them while doing the operation.

```
arr[len(arr)-1], arr[deleteIdx], arr = nil, arr[len(arr)-1], arr[:len(arr)-1]
//  ^ Setting the deleted index to nil ^
```

This is all, of course, if you don't care about preserving order.  If you do care, you will need to copy everything after `deleteIdx` starting over `deleteIdx`, which is O(n).  If you find yourself doing this, think if there isn't a better datastructure for your needs.

```
// Copy everything from [deleteIdx+1 .. n) onto [deleteIdx .. )
copy(arr[deleteIdx:], arr[deleteIdx+1:])
// arr[n - 1] and arr[n] have the same value (n = len(arr) - 1)
arr[len(arr)-1] = nil
// re-slice to reference only the n-1 elements
arr = arr[:len(arr)-1]
```

### Way to reinitialize a slice i.e. completely empty it but keep it

You can reinitialize a slice by re-slicing all its items out

```
// Keep everything from [0 .. 0), which means keep nothing
arr = arr[:0]
```

But there's a problem in doing this : as stated above, the backing array of the slice will still reference to the original items that were in the slice.  What you should do instead is create a new slice and let this one be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is manyfold:

1. You must realize that there is *no* slice without backing array and if you talk about a slice you always have to think about the backing array too.  Musing about this a bit leads to...
2. The second part of the question "reinitialize a slice i.e. completely empty it but still keep it" is very unclear. Do not think about slices in this way. `a = a[:0]` reslices `a` to zero length while keeping the backing array.
3. For everything else: Have a look at the "official" Slice Tricks https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks